# Is this possible to use non-sqlite database in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Title says all.
Can i use mysql/oracle database in Android application even if it's very slow and bad ?

Comment: You mean direct access to the MySQL / Oracle database without an API between them?

Comment: Yeah, i feel dumb now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remotely by using a webservice yes.

Locally , it's theorically possible but you probably have to :

- have a rooted phone
- recompile the source code of your DBMS to support the arm architecture (or whatever your phone use)
- find/create a driver for java (supported by dalvik) which support this DBMS
- find/create an api for this DBMS

Long story short , you don't want to do that ! It's cleary not a good solution.

And to be honest using DBMS like oracle on a phone , it is like using a rocket launcher to kill a fly ...

Note : you can have a look on [this documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/bdb-je-android-160932.pdf) about berkley DB on android

Comment: I know it's not a good question, but i have to anticipate the question for a viva. Thank you for your answer, you helped me a lot !

Comment: Why is rooting required?

Comment: I doubt you can build and install a new database on the system with a non rooted phone. I never tried it though, it just a guess

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you need local database running on Android. That means MySQL/Oracle are not choice.

As there is only java - you can try to use java based DB. There are few on internet. Of course they have to be ported.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can.

You just have to create .php that gonna get informations from the databases and return you a json.

In Android you create a httprequest in wich you target the .php file and analyze the json.